# how to select multiple Values for a lookup column?

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I have a list that has a lookup column that comes from external list records.

I want to select multiple records from the external list while setting the value of this lookup column ??

So how to select multiple Values for a lookup column ?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want http://sharepointcodeblock.blogspot.com/2008/07/properly-populating-and-retrieving.html

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is the [SPFieldLookupValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvaluecollection.aspx) object which will allow you to specify multiple lookup values for a field value.  Here is some sample code that gets two values from the "Options" list (based on ID, but you could use an `SPQuery`) and then creates a `SPFieldLookupValueCollection` based on those items.  It then sets the "OptionsLookup" field on the "TestList" list.

```
SPList optionsList = currentWeb.GetList(currentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "Lists/Options");
SPListItem value1 = optionsList.GetItemById(1);
SPListItem value2 = optionsList.GetItemById(2);
SPFieldLookupValueCollection optionValues = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection();
optionValues.Add(new SPFieldLookupValue(value1.ID, value1.Title));
optionValues.Add(new SPFieldLookupValue(value2.ID, value2.Title));

SPList oneList = currentWeb.GetList(currentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "Lists/TestList");
SPListItem addedItem = oneList.AddItem();
addedItem["Title"] = "Setting Multiple Values";
addedItem["OptionsLookup"] = optionValues;

addedItem.Update();
```